# Sphere parameterization with 6 patches

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, parametric

I am looking for a parameterization of the sphere with 6 patches, like in http://www.image.ucar.edu/staff/rnair/research09.html 
and the inverse of this parameterization.

As well, I would need a method to determine, for a point $x$ (which coordinates are known of course) on the sphere, which patch (patches for boundaries) $x$ lies in (with patches defined by the above parametrization).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: you get the parametrization by composing "parametrisation" of the surface of the cube and normalizing points of that surface viewed as vectors in a euclidean space.

How to determine which patch point belongs to? We know that points on the sphere are normalized points from the surface of the cube. So it is enough to find such a way of determining a face of the cube that behaves well with respect to change of length (normalization). Can you find such a method?

**EDIT**. I'll show two methods of determining the patch. Let's assume we are talking about the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3$ ($x^2+y^2+z^2=1$). The inscribed cube is $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\right]^3$.

Method 1. The top patch is that patch where $z>0$ and $|z|=\max(|x|,|y|,|z|)$. (It's obviously a correct method for the cube surface and it relies on inequalities between coordinates, so behaves well with respect to normalizing.) The same with the other patches.

Method 2. Note that the cube is a ball in the maximum ($\ell_\infty$) metric. So our surface may be described by the formula $\max(|x|, |y|, |z|)=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

Now: we have "parametrization" $g:\partial C\to S^2$ (from the cube surface to the sphere) given by normalization with respect to the euclidean metric. By the previous observation we can easily find its inverse - it's given by the formula (it's just normalizing with respect to the maximum metric + homothety):
$$g^{-1}(x,y,z) = \frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt3 \max(|x|,|y|,|z|)}.$$

So the second method is first use $g^{-1}$ and then just test which coordinate(s) are equal to $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

**EDIT2** I realized that $\pi/4$ from your link may not be a random mistake. Maybe they want a different parametrization, not coming from the natural parametrization of the cube surface (but maybe more natural for the sphere). Consider the following (for the top patch):

$$\varphi'(\alpha, \beta) = (
\sin\alpha \cdot \cos\beta,
\cos\alpha \cdot \sin\beta,
\cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta)$$
$$\varphi(\alpha, \beta)=\varphi'(\alpha, \beta)\cdot S\left(\varphi'(\alpha, \beta)\right)$$

Why this formula? $\pi/4$ is an angle - so I wanted the parametrization to be ingular in some sense. But I can't just take one vector and rotate it around one axis by $\alpha$ and then around another by $\beta$ - rotations are not be commutative and we want our solution to be symmetric.

It also translates nicely to the cube - if you normalize it with respect to the maximum metric (you can divide it by $\sqrt3$ if you prefer) you end up with a nonstandard parametrization of the top face of the cube:
$$(\tan\alpha, \tan\beta, 1).$$

**EDIT3** (the OP asked in comments for a version for an ellipsoid)

Let's consider an ellipsoid given by the formula $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. It is the image of the unit sphere under linear automorphism given in the standard basis by a diagonal matrix $D=\mathrm{diag}(a,b,c)$.

It seems that the requested projection is a projection from $[-a,a] \times [-b,b] \times [-c,c]$ (the case of projecting a cube was already discussed in the comments). But this case is actually trivial - if we apply $D^{-1}$ to our picture, we will get the known case of projecting the unit cube $[-1,1]^3$ onto the unit sphere.

**All together**

Actually we can handle all the cases (cube or cuboid, sphere or ellipsoid, the same parameters for cuboid and ellipsoid or different ones) in one go. We need to firstly: parametrize, secondly: determine the patch. The parametrization of the surface of a cube/cuboid is easy, the tricky thing is how to project it onto a sphere/ellipsoid. One of the ways of determining a patch is by projecting back onto the cube/cuboid. So all we need is projections.

Projections there and back are done by normalizing with respect to appropriate norm. So, projection to the surface of the cube $[-a,a] \times [-b,b] \times [-c,c]$ may be done with the formula $(x,y,z)\mapsto\frac{(x,y,z)}{\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty^{a,b,c}}$, where $\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty^{a,b,c}$ is given by the formula:
$$\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty^{a,b,c} = \left\|\left(\frac{x}{a},\frac{y}{b},\frac{z}{c}\right)\right\|_\infty.$$

Similarly, projection on the ellipse given by $\frac{x^2}{d^2} + \frac{y^2}{e^2} + \frac{z^2}{f^2}=1$ may be done with the formula $(x,y,z)\mapsto\frac{(x,y,z)}{\|(x,y,z)\|_2^{d,e,f}}$, where $\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty^{d,e,f}$ is given by:
$\|(x,y,z)\|_\infty^{d,e,f} = \left\|\left(\frac{x}{d},\frac{y}{e},\frac{z}{f}\right)\right\|_2.$

Comment: You actually mean cube surface squares, I suppose.

Comment: @ccorn Thanks! Of course I meant cube surface where I wrote square. Corrected.

Comment: @savick01 I was thinking about computing the distances from the point to the faces of the cube containing the sphere, and the patch would be given by the smallest distance. That implies testing all 6 distances. Do you have something faster ?

Comment: @HubertDubois Yes:) Leave the sphere. Focus on the cube - because as I said you should't rely on *length* (you can't test $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$), all you have is *shape* that is encoded by proportions of the coordinates. Clearer now:)?

Comment: You can also do something that is closer to your solution - cube is just a ball in $\ell_\infty$ metric - this makes it very easy to find the inverse of our parametrization (I mean find the function from the sphere to the surface of the cube) and then everything is trivial (you can test things like $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$).

Comment: @savick01 With $s=S(u,v,w)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{u^{2}+v^{2}+w^{2}}}$, the parameterization
could be: $f(u,v,w)=(u\times s,v\times s,w\times s)=(x,y,z).$

You take $tan(u)$ and $tan(v)$ in $S$ if you want $[-\Pi/4,\Pi/4]$
instead of $[-1,1]$. But I do not see why you ``can't test $\Pi/4$
`` ? The 6 distances from $(x,y,z)$ to $\{x=+/-1\},$ $\{y=+/-1\},$
$\{z=+/-1\},$ are resp. $x-1,x+1$, etc...

Could you edit your answear and provide your solution, as well as
the one with ``$l_{\infty}$ metric'' , I think that would clarify
everything ? Thanks !

Comment: @HubertDubois 1. Forget about $\pi/4$, I took it from your link, but it should be $1/\sqrt3$ for the unit sphere. 2. I think rescaling is more handy than $\tan$ ;) 3. Of course you can test the distance from those affine hypersurfaces (but you need to proof that it is a correct method), but you can't test the equality (testing equality is ok for the cube, not the sphere). 4. I provided my methods, it should be clear now.

Comment: @HubertDubois I added something new! Please write later what solution was expected by your teacher:)

Comment: @savick01 Would you have a similar parameterization for an ellipsoïd (again "cubed" with 6 patches), and an easy way to determine the patch containing any given point of the ellipsoïd (I think using the $l_{\infty}$ norm will not work for the ellipsoïd) ?

Comment: @HubertDubois The first parametrization is still valid - you just normalize not with respect to the standard euclidean metric, but with respect to such a metric that the elipsoid is a sphere (if the elipsoide is given by equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$ then the proper norm is just $\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}}$). It is a metric since by a linear isomorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ you can translate it to the standard euclidean metric.

Comment: Well, the second is valid too, if you change the definition of $S$ appropriately. But I don't know if it is particularly handy.

Comment: Coming to the methods of determining patches: they are still valid (you only need to correct $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ if necessary).

Comment: In the above I'm assuming that you are still inscribing a cube. If you want to inscribe something else, please clarify.

Comment: I am using the following parameterization:

$s(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$

$f_{1}:]-1,1[^{2}\rightarrow Patch\,1$

$\:\,\:(u,v)\rightarrow(a\times s(a,bu,cv),bu\times s(a,bu,cv),cv\times s(a,bu,cv))$

Comment: And the same idea for the 5 other patches (such parameterization gives
me grid elements that are about the same ``size'' from one patch
to another).

For the sphere, I just used your method : find which component is
equal to ${+}{-}1$ in $\dfrac{(x,y,z)}{|(x,y,z)|_{\infty}}$,
that gives the patch containing $(x,y,z).$ Now I need the same method
for the ellipsoïd, with the parameterization above (it then will depend
on a, b and c I think).