# Reconstruct a sphere from 6 patches

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

Let's say that I need to reconstruct a surface that could be cloned 6 times to create a perfect sphere.

It is sampled in some finite N elements per side so the patch will have NxN elements (vertex)

So I will iterate from -0.5 to 0.5 in XY axis being 0 0 the center of my patch.

Ideally I was about iterating like that

```
sphericalTheta = xpos * (pi / 2.0);
sphericalPhi = ypos * (pi / 2.0);
```

Being xpos and ypos the iterators over that -0.5 0.5 range

so I expected that this should work:

```
mX = cos(sphericalPhi) * sin(sphericalTheta);
mY = cos(sphericalPhi) * cos(sphericalTheta);
mZ = sin(sphericalPhi);
```

but obviously it didn't work[image: First try]

Seeing that result intuitively I notice that I should modify my iterators since -0.5 0.5 only works when the other coordinate in the pair is 0

```
newypos = ypos * cos(abs(xpos)* (pi / 3.0));
newxpos = xpos * cos(abs(ypos)* (pi / 3.0));
sphericalTheta = newxpos * (pi / 2.0);
sphericalPhi = newypos * (pi / 2.0);
```

[image: Test 2]

It gets better but still it has some overlaps.

Side note: this is NOT the same as [Sphere parameterization with 6 patches](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454354/sphere-parameterization-with-6-patches)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to format.

Comment: Your very dark blue screen copies do not help to understand your issue (the first one in particular is useless). You should provide a drawing of what you want (you have said what you do not want : mapping from of a cube). Is your idea a mapping from a double tetrahedron (two tetrahedra assembled upside down with a common base) ?

Comment: I mean something like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74941/how-do-you-parameterize-a-sphere-so-that-there-are-6-faces

Comment: Therefore, can I say that you are" looking for way to descrbe the contour (and the interior) of the central projection of the face of a cube onto its curcumscribed sphere". If you want to acknowlege somebody, please write in front of your  comment @pseudo (I wasn't aware for example that you had answered me).